# SSRS report BorderStyle

Tags: html, css, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report with 1 Tablix control. I want to have certain rows with a top border. I have achieved this by using expression in Top Border: `=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) MOD 2 = 0, "Solid", "None")`.

This achieves the effect that each "cell" is two rows high. This works flawlessly in Internet Explorer 9, 10 & 11, but not in Chrome, Firefox or IE7! I will deploy this as a local report through an ASP page. Is there anything I can do to make this work on all browsers?

Comment: How thick are your lines. IE and FF will render 0.5 for border width but this sill not show up in chrome.

Comment: Lines are 1pt. Thank to your comment, I think I have found another way to achieve my goal. Setting the Top Border color to the same as the background with the expression doesn't work either, but, set all border colors to a light color and with the expression set the top border to a dark color gives a nasty version of what I am looking for. I also double the border to 2pt.